# "These" or "those" with abstract thing?

Tags: word-choice, demonstrative-pronouns

> **Alternative energy sources** are renewable and are thought to be "free"
>   energy sources. ***They*** all have lower carbon emissions compared to
>   conventional energy resources. ***These*** include Biomass Energy, Wind
>   Energy, Solar Energy,...

(http://www.altenergy.org)

It's not about the distance thing.
So, Why "these"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We tend to use **these** not just when objects are closer but also when we are referring back to items we have just mentioned.

In the example, **these** means **these sources** (just referred to). *Sources* is elided but understood.

It's another way of saying **they** with a slightly different nuance, emphasising the back reference.

Similar examples might be:

> The locals are noisy. These (*people*) are not people I want to associate with.

> The library books are grubby. These (*books*) are not fit for public use.

> His reasons are not credible. These (*excuses*) are not excuses that I can accept.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20220825044123/https://www.lexico.com/grammar/these-or-those)

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/determiners/this-that-these-those

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your detailed answer with these links.